Unable to Set Dynamic TTL for Redis Cache in NestJS
I’m trying to set a TTL (time-to-live) for caching specific data in my NestJS application. I need to apply dynamic TTL values based on each module, rather than using a common generic setting.
import { Cache, CACHE_MANAGER } from "@nestjs/cache-manager";
constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache) {}


async set<T>(key: string, value: T, ttl?: number): Promise<void> {
    const serializedValue = JSON.stringify(value); 
    await this.cacheManager.set(key, serializedValue, {ttl}); 
}

Am getting the below error while setting up the ttl like above,
Argument of type '{ ttl: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)

However, it keeps defaulting to some value around 85 minutes when executing code as below, and I’m not sure why this is happening.
await this.cacheManager.set(key, serializedValue, ttl);

My Module Versions are as below,
"@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.2.2",
"cache-manager": "^5.7.6",
"cache-manager-redis-store": "^2.0.0",


Add cache like this
await this.cacheManager.set(key, serializedValue,  { ttl: ttl ?? 5 } as any);

import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import { CacheStoreBase } from './cache.abstract';

@Injectable()
export class CacheStore extends CacheStoreBase {
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache) {
    super();
  }

  async deleteValue(key: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.cache.del(key);
  }

  async resetAll(): Promise<void> {
    await this.cache.reset();
  }

  async getValue(key: string): Promise<Object | undefined> {
    const value = await this.cache.get(key);
    return value || undefined;
  }

  async setValue(key: string, value: Object, ttl?: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.cache.set(key, value, { ttl: ttl ?? 5 } as any);
  }
}

